# Print array 3 lines

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to print this array of 9 elements out in 3 lines.

I want to print it out in 3 lines with 3 rows such as .

```
xxx
xxx
xxx
```

But i am not sure how to tackle that.

```
void ticTacToeBoard ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        cout << ticTacBoard[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to be verbose with my loops, so try this:

```
void ticTacToeBoard ()
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; i < 3; x++)
        {
            cout << ticTacBoard[3 * y + x] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Basically, I iterate over your board in rows (`y`), and then in columns (`x`), allowing me to print each cell *and* control the flow.

I just print a newline (`endl`) after each row.

Comment: Oh wow that looks nice. I have a question why do you multiple the 3 x y + z?

Comment: Because `3` is the number of items in each row. Every time you move down a row, your counter increases by `3`. Using a 2D array would get rid of this piece of code.

Comment: How can i get it so it prints out 1 to 9 instead of 0 to 8?

Comment: What do you mean? How's your board setup?

Comment: It should be a basic tic tac toe board that shows 1 to 9 for positions. But for some reason its showing 0 to 8 when using this to output check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042850/array-not-outputting-what-its-given

Comment: That answer is correct. `i` starts off at `0` and loops until it is equal to `8`. Just set each tile's value to `i + 1` instead of `i`.

Comment: See my answer to your linked question if you want another possible way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Change ticTacBoard to a two dimensional array and do

```
 using namespace std;


int main()
{

    int ticTacBoard[3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cout << ticTacBoard[i][j] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

A two dimensional array will be easier to understand.

Comment: I am using a one dimension here though

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulo operator to detect every third iteration. Then print a newline.

```
void ticTacToeBoard ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        cout << ticTacBoard[i] << " ";

        if((i + 1) % 3 == 0) {
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch frot the offset in a single-dimensional array (say i) to the offset in a bi-dimensional  via this simple formula:

```
row = i div width
column = i mod width
```

So, basically:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    cout << ticTacBoard[i];

    if(i % 3 == 2)
        cout << endl;
    else
        cout << ' ';
}
```