# Outputted array values different from the values stored

Tags: c++, arrays

I made an array and set the values from 1 to 9 in the `initializeBoard` function, but for some reason when I print the values they come out 0 to 8. Why is this happening? Shouldn't it print out 1 to 9 since those are the numbers I put in the array in `initializeBoard`?

```
int main()
{
    initializeBoard();
    ticTacToeBoard();
}

void initializeBoard()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
        ticTacBoard[i] = i;
    cout << endl;
}

void ticTacToeBoard ()
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            cout << ticTacBoard[3 * y + x] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have an [off-by-one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). Arrays use [zero-based indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) in C++. Your code does not assign a value to the zero<sup>th</sup> element of the array.

Try this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    ticTacBoard[i] = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: Whoa!! Why is the + 1 doing that?

Comment: Why couldnt i just start from int i = 1?

Comment: @mystycs: If you start from 1 you don't assign any value to the zeroth element in the array.

Comment: arrays in c++ are zero based. so the first item in the array is ticTacBoard[0], and you want to put a 1 in it, hence ticTacBoard[i]=i+1; if you use for(int i=1;i<10;i++) then you still need to assign values to the array like so: ticTacBoard[i-1]=i;

Comment: You could, but if your loop starts at `i=1` you'd want to use `[i-1]` to access your array. And make sure your loop to initialize the board has 3x3 = 9 slots (`i=1; i<=9; i++` or `i=0; i<9; i++` would work).

Answer (score 2):

The loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
{
    ticTacBoard[i] = i;
}
```

will only do 1-8 since it will stop when i++ increases it to 9, so you're not initializing all 9 elements.

You should realistically do the same loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    ticTacBoard[i] = (i + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies in:

```
ticTacBoard[i] = i;
```

Should be:

```
ticTacBoard[i-1] = i;
```

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

- Shouldn't you initialize `ticTacBoard` before accessing it with `[]`? Make sure you give it enough memory for all of your slots! (I'm guessing you're doing tic tac toe, so you'll want 3x3 = 9 slots)
- Indexing in C++ starts at 0. You want to do `for (i=0; i<9; i++)`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Your `i` starts at `0`, so your first value will be `0`. Since the inequality `i < 9` breaks when `i = 9`, `i` is actually never `9` (the loop exits before your code is actually run).

Try using `<=` instead of just `<` to account for `i = 9`:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
{
    ticTacBoard[i - 1] = i;
}
```

Other than that, arrays are indexed starting from `0` in C++ (and virtually every other language), so the first element is `array[0]`, second is `array[1]`, etc.

You'll have to subtract `1` from your array index.

Comment: Not really. See this code: http://jsfiddle.net/bXdyr/4/. It's JS, but it follows the same rules.

Comment: Huh, I could have sworn you didn't mention the `-1` offset when I posted that comment, but I can't remove the -1 vote until it's edited, so SO thinks it was there.